# Boost converter duty cycle

Tags: diodes, dc-dc-converter, boost, duty-cycle

[image]

In my circuit, I’m trying to solve the duty cycle to obtain an average dissipation of 5 W in the diode.

- Input voltage: 100 V
- Inductor: 10 mH
- RL: 100 Ω
- C: 10 uF
- Freq: 10 kHz
- Diode on voltage: 0.7 V

This is my thought process, run Pavg equation for the diode. I’m getting 714 A. Don’t think my setup is correct.

I’ve changed my frequency to time. 100 us.

Is my approach correct?

Comment: Welcome! Engineering tip: uS = microsiemens. us = microsecond.

Comment: Please show your work for Pavg.

Comment: @winny Actually, it's μs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *This is my thought process, run Pavg equation for the diode. I’m
> getting 714 A. Don’t think my setup is correct.*

It won't be anywhere 714 amps. If the forward volt drop is 0.7 volts then, if connected to DC, the forward current to dissipate 5 watts would be 5/0.7 = 7.143 amps. It seems like your calculation is out by 100:1 but, you didn't show your calculation so, it's impossible to say.

That's on DC but, in a boost converter the diode is only conducting when the MOSFET is activated so the current needed to dissipate 5 watts will naturally be higher but unlikely to be 714 amps unless the duty cycle is very nearly 100%.

So, on a 50% duty cycle the diode has to dissipate 10 watts when the MOSFET switches off. 10 watts and 0.7 volts implies a current of 14.286 amps. For a 75% duty cycle the current will be 28.57 amps.

At these sorts of current, I can tell the boost converter will be operating in CCM and, with the size of the inductance, it will be heavily into CCM.

Does this help you?

Comment: I’ll keep working it with this path. Thank you. I’ll respond back with the end result

Comment: Hint:  The average current through the diode is the same as the average current through the resistor.  Figure out what voltage (average) you need across the resistor, then go to https://www.electronicdesign.com/technologies/power/whitepaper/21252189/analog-devices-how-to-overcome-the-limits-of-boost-converters to see how to use it.

Comment: @Andy aka I got it. 
You were right. Simple dissipation equation of the diode. 7.142 amps. 
Utilize that to calculate V_out. 714.286V. 
Then use a solve function for D. 
Vout=VDD/(1-D). 86%